# iOS 3.2 to iOS 7 interface orientation inconsistency

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a very old app that's compatible with iOS 3.2+ devices (both iPads and iPhones). And I have a big issue making it compatible with iOS 7!

In fact, it has been written long ago before ARC, storyboards and all that syntactic sugar we are pleased to play with nowadays. And I'm having a very hard time trying understanding some interface orientation issue:

For the iPhone, the app is only visible in landscape... No problemo with the main ViewController. But the settings one (a simple ViewController with a UITableView in it) is always displayed in Portrait !!! Whatever the properties I set and the methods I write.

In the `.plist` I have only supported orientations LandscapeLeft and Right. In the Settings View Controller, I have those methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation) || (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone);
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)?UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

But what really bothers me is that when I display `self.interfaceOrientation` it says Landscape (in the `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews`).

But the most weird, is that the status bar is in Landscape, over the Portrait ViewController!!!

(Of course, the problem appears both on device and simulator)

So if someone can help putting back that ViewController all in Landscape. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any analytics to show if anyone is using it on iOS 3 (or 4) and whether you should continue to support those versions?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. But if you have a solution that works on iOS 5+ I'm glad to hear it, and I'll bring it back to iOS 4-...

Comment: You say that your plist only said landscape modes. Don't you have to support portrait there, too? Then specify permitted orientations view controller by view controller.

Comment: I've tried with Portrait allowed within the `.plist` and it doesn't change the problem. The first ViewController is correct, but the second still is in portrait...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well at last, I eventually found it!!!

The problem was (I still don't know exactly why) caused by the way I was switching between ViewControllers (the old iOS 3 way).

So to correct if, I test if the method `presentViewController:animated:completion` is available (God bless `respondsToSelector:`) and I use it when I can.

Problem solved!